# Hide only text in html paragraph

Tags: html, css

I want to hide text in paragraph, but there are one image and some text on it. When I'm using css to display none so all paragraph are hidden...but I want to only hide the text not image.
Here is the code.

```
<p>
  <a href="/_blog/News_and_Inspiration/post/Cooking_up_a_storm/"><img alt="" style="border: 0px solid; width: 100px; height: 150px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" src="/images/blog/Shaun-Clouston.jpg" /></a>
    The executive chef of Wellington&rsquo;s award winning  Restaurant, Shaun Clouston is just one of the award winning New Zealand Beef and Lamb Ambassador chefs we have cooking up a storm at our Rural Women New Zealand Beef + Lamb Cooking Demonstrations over the coming months.&nbsp;
</p>

<p>
  <img src="/images/blog/Southland Life Education Trust Car 2.jpg" alt="">
  Two years ago the Southland Life Education Community Trust approached our four Southland Provincials, asking for assistance to replace their educator’s car, as the current one needed major repairs.
</p>
```

Comment: Code was better than this image preview.

Comment: @svs dont you have OCR ?

Comment: It will work if you can put the text inside a `<span>` - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JHtPR/). Please put code as text, not as image.

Comment: Below given answers are not solutions, its just hacks. it wiill not fulfill the the need of any layout in my opinion.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
p {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

And specify the font-size for any descendent elements you want visible.

Comment: Clever.  So long as the text isn't too long you MIGHT be able to get away with setting `color` to `white`, or if you're really lucky, `transparent` for IE8- where the text still shows

Comment: @asif : You should accept his anwser to indicate your issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes, agree with @PeeHaa IE 8 and below don't seem to like this. But, this is creative and it works good for my situation! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the rest of your layout and whether you need to stick to `display: none;` for hiding the content, you can `visbility: hidden;` use like in the following example:

```
p {
   visibility: hidden;
}

img {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

See example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzuhH/).

Comment: This is actually a really good answer, but emphasis has to be put on _depending on the rest of your layout_ as `visibility: hidden` elements can still take up room on the page.  It's a shame that `display: none` is necessarily inherited, although I guess that it makes more sense that way.

Comment: @asif So you should accept his answer to show other, that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
    p{
        text-indent: -1000px;
    }
    img{
        position: absolute;
        left:10px; /*obviously position how you like*/
    }
```

Comment: If the text is very long, `letter-spacing: -negative value` could also help

Answer (score 2):

Many options are there,

1. text and background same color
2. font size 0px
3. display none
4. visibility: hidden
   and many more are there...

If helped, nice. 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

you can take your text into span and make it display:none; hope this will help you :)

```
  p span {
display:none;
}

<p>
  <a href="/_blog/News_and_Inspiration/post/Cooking_up_a_storm/"><img alt="" style="border: 0px solid; width: 100px; height: 150px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" src="/images/blog/Shaun-Clouston.jpg" /></a>
  <span>The executive chef of Wellington&rsquo;s award winning  Restaurant, Shaun Clouston is just one of the award winning New Zealand Beef and Lamb Ambassador chefs we have cooking up a storm at our Rural Women New Zealand Beef + Lamb Cooking Demonstrations over the coming months.&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works too!
Just hide the innerHTML text and keep other components.

```
  <div id="container" style={{color:'transparent'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}></div>
```